# How to bind the value separately returned from the component

Tags: vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js

I've imported the same child component twice in a component, and used `$emit()` and `$on` to get the result from the child component. Now I want to bind the value returned to each component.

For example, if I clicked stars in `dimensionA` as `2`, the `dimensionA :: {{dimensionA}}` should display `dimensionA :: 2` and the same with `dimensionB`. Any help?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbwejLrL/29/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) instead of passing props, as you want two way data binding between your parent and child component. If you look at [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events),

```
<input v-model="something">
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
<input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
```

So for a component to work with v-model, it must:

- accept a value prop
- emit an input event with the new value

I have modified your fiddle with these changes, have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ne967jba/7/).

Comment: But the stars will not be rendered properly now, when the page refresh, it should be 1 star and 2 stars in `dimensionA` and `dimensionB` respectively.

Comment: @JonX I forgot to update variable used in watch: check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ne967jba/7/)